# How to plot vertical line in octave?

Tags: octave, line-plot

What it the best way to plot a vertical line using Octave?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, I have two methods for this. One, I found, and the other I made up.

Method 1: From [here](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/How-to-draw-a-vertical-line-td1605721.html).

```
%% Set x value where verticle line should intersect the x-axis.
x = 0;
%% plot a line between two points using plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2])
plot([x,x],[-10,10]);
```

Method 2: A slightly different approach, exact same result

```
%% Setup a vector of x values
x = linspace(0,0,100);
%% Setup a vector of y values
y = linspace(0,10,100);
%% Plot the paired points in a line
plot(x,y);
```

I think Method 2 may write more information to memory before the plot process and it's a line longer, so in my eyes, Method 1 should be the better option. If you prefer Method 2, make sure your x and y vectors are the same dimension or you'll end up with a bunch of dots where you're line should be.

Comment: your Method 2 is not only more memory before the plot, it takes more memory all the time. The data used to make a plot is still in the figure (take a look at the `cdata` in the figure properties). And your method 1 works fine, why making it more complicated by showing a worse way to do exactly the same thing?

Comment: @carandraug the second method is even the recommended way in the octave programming tutorial to get a dotted vertical asymptote lines (compare https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Octave_Programming_Tutorial/Getting_started)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the *Octave* documentation for doing *obvious* things can be ridiculously lousy with no working examples. Drawing a simple line on top of a plot is one.

As already mentioned, it's is very silly to **plot** *straight* lines in octave. It's a waste of memory and processing. Instead use the **`line()`** function, to *draw* on top of your plot.

The *line()* function require 2 non-standard *x-values* and *y-values* vectors, instead of the standard *point-slope* arguments for point `A` and point `B`, normally represented by `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)`. Instead, you need to write this as: **`X=(x1,x2)`** and **`Y=(y1,y2)`**. Thus confusing every living soul!

Here is an example of the correct way to do this in *Octave* language:

```
pkg load statistics     % Need to load the statistics package
x = randn (1,1000);     % Normal Distribution of random numbers
clf; histfit(x)         % Make a histogram plot of x and fit the data
ylim ([-20,100])        % Change the plot limits (to lift graph up)

% Draw the (vertical) line between (0,-10) and (0,90)
line ("xdata",[0,0], "ydata",[-10,90], "linewidth", 3)
```

With the result:

[image]

Comment: `plot` produces the exact same result as `line`, it is a high-level interface for the low-level `line` function. The inputs are the same, except with `line` you need to specify everything as key-value pairs. There is no advantage to using `line` IMO.

Answer (score 0):

notation (x1,x2),(y1,y2) is really confusing and against textbooks.

Anyway, this is my way:

```
figure;
hold on;
% vertical line x=0
plot([0,0],[0,10]);
%horizontal line y=0
plot([0,10],[0,0]);
% vertical line x=2
plot([2,2],[0,10]);
hold off;
```

[image]